# Unable to debug lInux on gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I am trying to debug Linux using gdb, I compiled kernel with "compile kernel with debug info".
    once kernel is compiled I am trying to give 
    GDB file vmlinux
    (running above command gives me below error)

```
 GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1


Reading symbols from file...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
"/home/Linux/vmlinux" is not a core dump: File format not recognized
```

Even I am setting debug con-figs it is giving me "no debugging symbols found"

Comment: What is the command line you are using to invoke gdb, and have you read `man gdb`?

Answer (score 6):

kernel debugging is a whole different ballgame from debugging a user process and is not as simple as firing up GDB. For this you will need support of a JTAG. 
[QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) allows you to virtualize a machine and therefore use a virtual JTAG.

For simple stuff you will probably find `printk` much easier.

Comment: Another possibility is using [KDB](http://elinux.org/KDB) (or KGDB), which can be used via a serial console or a connected keyboard

Comment: Thank you, i am trying to run linux kernel on QEMU, i ran qemu-system-i386 -s -S -kernel bzImage and gdb file vmlinux command is giving  above error